# I have a problem exporting a .obj file into Blender version 2.78

Tags: rendering, objects, export

Hi so recently in the past 3 hours, I had decided to render some objects for a friend of mine. I was able able to use blender yesterday just fine. So today when I went to go export a .obj file, the title of the file became highlighted in red, when you would move your cursor over the text it would say, "Filename, overwrite existing" when you click export OBJ, nothing happens. I tried using a different file and the same thing occurred. I don't get any error messages on my screen. I've tried looking up my problem on the web, hoping to find someone with the same problem, unfortunately, I feel like this problem has only affected me. So I come here looking for any advice, tips, or even a full out solution to help me resolve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: If the filename is red, that generally means you're trying to save to a file that already exists.

Comment: All of this would make sense, but it's all of the files that are.obj which are given the red highlight. If this is the case then how exactly can I export these files into blender, since I'm not really trying to save, I'm just trying to export them onto the application so I can work on them.